# RangeBand Not Including All Bars

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My implementation of rangeBand includes a portion but not all bars that are entering.

My dataset has 19 positions and 12 are showing up in the chart.

Have tried changing the interval on rangeBand to the length of data, to a much larger width and various other options.

What should the interval be in order to fit in all of the bars/items in the data array?

```
const data  =  [
 {key: "April", value: 5283},
 {key: "May", value: 5361},
 {key: "June", value: 5761},
 {key: "July", value:  5349},
 {key: "August", value:  4729},
 {key: "September", value: 4657},
 {key: "October", value: 4183},
 {key: "November", value: 3428},
 {key: "December", value: 4281},
 {key: "January", value: 3284},
 {key: "February", value: 3576},
 {key: "March", value: 5417},
 {key: "April", value: 5517},
 {key: "May", value: 5916},
 {key: "June", value: 6104},
 {key: "July", value: 5342},
 {key: "August", value: 5573},
 {key: "September", value: 5211},
 {key: "October", value: 3248},
];

var w = 1000;
var h = 450;

var margin = {
 top: 30,
 bottom: 50,
 left: 10,
 right: 60
};

let width = w - margin.left - margin.right;
let height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom;
let barOuterPad = .1;
let barPad = .025;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(data.map(function(entry){
        return entry.key;
    }))
    .rangeBands([0, width],barPad, barOuterPad);
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
        return d.value;
    })])
    .range([height, 0]);
var ordinalColorScale = d3.scale.category20();
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");
var yGridlines = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .tickSize(-width,0,0)
            .tickFormat("")
            .orient("left");
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("id", "chart")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);
var chart = svg.append("g")
        .classed("display", true)
        .attr("transform",
         "translate(" + margin.left + "," +  margin.top + ")");
function plot(params){
 this.append("g")
    .call(yGridlines)
    .classed("gridline", true)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");
this.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(params.data)
    .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .classed("bar", true)
        .attr("x", function(d){
            return x(d.key);
        })
        .attr("y", function(d){
            return y(d.value);
        })
        .attr("height", function(d){
            return height - y(d.value);
        })
        .attr("width", function(){
            return x.rangeBand();
        })
        .style("fill", function(i){
            return ordinalColorScale(i);
        });

this.selectAll(".bar-label")
    .data(params.data)
    .enter()
        .append("text")
        .classed("bar-label", true)
        .attr("x", function(d,i){
            return x(d.key) + (x.rangeBand()/2)
        })
        .attr("dx", 0)
        .attr("y", function(d){
            return y(d.value);
        })
        .attr("dy", -6)
        .text(function(d){
            return d.value;
        });
   this.append("g")
    .classed("x axis", true)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", -8)
    .attr("dy", 8)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0) rotate(-45)");

this.append("g")
    .classed("y axis", true)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    .call(yAxis);

this.select(".y.axis")
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-50," + height/2 + ") rotate(-90)")
    .text("Units Sold");

this.select(".x.axis")
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .text("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + ", 80)")
    .text("Date");
}
plot.call(chart, {data: data});
}
```

Comment: I think your problem is due to the fact that have duplicate keys in your data. The `x` domain is mapping each key to a single index, so your duplicates are getting mapped to the same column. Perhaps use a different key? It's hard to know without more info on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was that my keys weren't unique.

I added '15 and '16 to each month and all the bars showed up!